# can not full screen panel on android device use sencha touch 2.0 RC

Tags: android, touch, extjs

I am trying to make a full screen panel on android, but I can't do it.
Few height is spacer.

I can insert full screen html script only.

How can I do full screen sencha touch panel on android?

Does anyone have any ideas why this is happening?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here what i did in order to have my application fullscreen :

> requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
>
> getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
>
> WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
>
> getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

If you want that or something else?